# Environment for rc.local

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables, boot

I need to create an environment variable that is set within a bash script. I want this environment variable to be a system wide environment variable and I also want to be able to use it in an if condition in rc.local. So far I have tried /etc/profile but rc.local does not see it when I set it there.

Which script should I set this environment variable in so that rc.local can see it when I boot?

Other question while I’m at it. Who starts rc.local?

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Rc.local runs before the operating system is fully booted but has not yet started the login shell, so the environment variables we configured in /etc/profiles or bashrc are not executed, so no environment variables are visible during the rc.local implementation phase.
The solution is:
**Add export ENVNAME=*********** before the command in rc.local**